# SQL statement to find for each match

Tags: sql

It is IPL season. The following are the IPL matches database relations:

`Player(playerid, name, playsfor)` :Contains details of each player and the team he plays for. Playsfor references teamid in Team table.

`Team(teamid, teamname)`: Contains team id and team name.

`Playerbat(playerid, matchid, runsscored,teamid)`: Contains runs scored by a player in each match. Has a row for the player only if the player plays in the match.

`Playerbowl(playerid, matchid, wicketstaken,teamid)`: Contains wickets taken by a player in each match. Has a row for the player only if the player plays in the match.

`PlayersmatchDetails (Playerid, Matchid)` : Contains the player names who have played in the match.

By using above tables, Write an SQL statement to find for each match, the total runs scored by each team which has played atleast one match.

Note1: The column(s) to be displayed in the result or output should be matchid and Runs only.

Note2: While writing SQL query, you are required to write the table name as schemaname.tablename (For example employee.projectDetails where employee is schemaname and projectDetails is tablename).

Comment: How can you represent **the total runs scored by each team** this if you show only `matchid` and `runs`. What is your schema namd? `IPL`?

Comment: please give sample table with your desired result.

Comment: looks like a homework. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of assumptions based on Note1 and Note2.

Note1: You state you only want the columns matchid and Runs, but the description says the runs scored by each team, therefore you need to have the team in the output as well, so my answer contains matchid, teamname, Runs as outputs.

Note2: You don't specify a schema name so I'll assume all tables are in a schema called schemaname. You need to replace this with the correct schema name.

```
SELECT pb.matchid, t.teamname, SUM(pb.runsscored) as Runs
FROM schemaname.Playerbat pb
INNER JOIN schemaname.Team t ON t.teamid = pb.teamid
GROUP BY pb.matchid, t.teamname
ORDER BY t.teamname, pb.matchid
```